# How do I pass variables through AWS Codepipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

AWS CodePipeline orchestrates first `lambda-A` and then `lambda-B` and i want to pass a variable from my `lambda-A` to my `lambda-B`.

In `lambda-A` i set the outputVariables when setting the job to success:

```
boto3.client("codepipeline").put_job_success_result(
        jobId=event["CodePipeline.job"]["id"],
        outputVariables={"FOO":"BAR"}
    )
```

> From the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codepipeline.html#CodePipeline.Client.put_job_success_result) i know that `outputVariables` are Key-value pairs that can be made available to a downstream action.

CodePipeline then triggers `lambda-B`. How can i retrieve in `lambda-B` the variables i have set in the outputVariables in `lambda-A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lambda-B's action configuration, in User parameters, enter the variable syntax to ingest the variable created in earlier action using this syntax:

```
#{outputVariables.FOO}
```

Then you can unpack the 'UserParameters' in Lambda function:

```
{
    "CodePipeline.job": {
        "id": "EXAMPLE-e08a-4f06-b9ba-EXAMPLE",
        "accountId": "EXAMPLE87397",
        "data": {
            "actionConfiguration": {
                "configuration": {
                    "FunctionName": "LambdaForCP-Python",
                    "UserParameters": "5e2591fd79889dEXAMPLE5f33e2"
                }
            },
```

from 'event':

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print(event)
```

This procedure is detailed in Step (f) here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-lambda-variables.html#lambda-variables-pipeline